Issue with Environment Variable in React - Getting undefined in URL
.env
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/

.js
const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;
const url = `${baseUrl}WP/SiteLoginAPI/`;
console.log('Constructed URL:', url);

Problem
The constructed URL contains undefined, leading to a 404 error:
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/undefinedWP/SiteLoginAPI/

What could be causing process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL to be undefined on the server, and how can I ensure it is correctly set?
It must be something simple that I'm just missing. But I haven't been able to figure it out.
I found a similar question here but it also not helping.

What is supposed to be providing process.env? It doesn't really exist in the browser environment.

@Mudasir Habib If possible, share your code what you have tried.

my code is working fine locally but issue is on server
on server i can see baseUrl in logs as
"https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/"
@jonrsharpe

@Mudasir Habib Are you using Dotenv package?

@Mudasir Habib Are you looking for this.

I tried Sample react app to fetch the environment variable in Azure App Service.

If you are deploying through GitHub or DevOps verify that the deployment script or pipeline is not overwriting or ignoring the .env file.
Make sure that the .env file is located in the root directory of the App Service project.



Check if there are any extra spaces, missing characters, or any other typos in the .env file or when accessing the variable in your code.

Install the dotenv package using below command.
pip install dotenv

Below is the code used to fetch the environment variables.
App.js:
import React from 'react';
function App() {
  const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;
  const url = `${baseUrl}WP/SiteLoginAPI/`;
  console.log('Constructed URL:', url);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Environment Variable Example</h1>
      <p>Constructed URL: {url}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;

For Production use .env.production, different environments (development, testing, production) often require different configurations.
Environment variables in .env.productioncan be managed through deployment pipelines or secrets management tools.
.env:
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=https://<AzureWebAppName>.azurewebsites.net/

process.env is used to access environment variables that have been defined in .env files or set during the build process.
Azure App Service Output:

If you're still facing the issue with local configuration add key values in Environment Variables of the Azure App service as shown below.


Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
